# RuboCop - [AllCops -> Exclude] not working in GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions, rubocop

The RuboCop `AllCops->Exclude` rule does not work using GitHub Actions.

> It seems to go into a recursive loop

I have a simple GEM that is using RuboCop with a basic configuration.

```yaml
AllCops:
  TargetRubyVersion: 2.7
  NewCops: enable

Style/StringLiterals:
  Enabled: true
  EnforcedStyle: double_quotes

Style/StringLiteralsInInterpolation:
  Enabled: true
  EnforcedStyle: double_quotes

Layout/LineLength:
  Max: 120
```

I need to disable cop rules in two folders.

```yaml
AllCops:
  TargetRubyVersion: 2.7
  NewCops: enable
  Exclude:
    - ".builders/**/*"
    - "spec/samples/**/*"
```

### WORKS :) Run Rubocop locally with excluded files:

[image]

## Using GitHub Actions

### WORKS :) Run RuboCop without `AllCops->Exclude`

[GHA k_director/runs/4909797149](https://github.com/klueless-io/k_director/runs/4909797149)

[image]

### FAILS :( Run RuboCop sing `AllCops->Exclude`

[GHA k_director/runs/4909833222](https://github.com/klueless-io/k_director/runs/4909833222)

I cancelled the workflow at nearly 8 minutes

[image]

This action takes it seems to go into a deep tree traversal and locks up my GitHub Actions.

Here is some of the errors 1800 lines into the log

[image]

### GitHub Action workflow for RuboCop

```yaml
name: Build Application

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Ruby ${{ matrix.ruby }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        ruby: ['2.7.1']

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Ruby
      uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
      with:
        ruby-version: ${{ matrix.ruby }}
        bundler-cache: true

    - name: Run rubocop
      run: bundle exec rubocop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first tried to the venders directory into the exclusions.

```yaml
AllCops:
  Exclude:
    - 'vendor/**/*'
```

I found the answer here: [How to Setup RuboCop in GitHub Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69870994/how-to-setup-rubocop-in-github-actions)

This worked for me, but @AndyWait pointed me to a section in the documentation and my current working solution is to add the following, which will merge my new exclusions with the exclusions that are in the rubocop->default.yml

```yaml
inherit_mode:
  merge:
    - Exclude
```

Additionally, configuration is inherited from `.rubocop.yml' files further up the folder hierarchy, aka parent folders.

If you want to avoid those configuration files being included when rubocop runs, then pass in the specific `.rubocop.yml` file that is needed for configuration and let it reference other files as needed using the `inherit_from: ../.some_other_rubocop.yml` option.

```
rubocop --config .rubocop.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

RuboCop already excludes `vendor/**/*` by default:

https://github.com/rubocop/rubocop/blob/77b54824b74db4d36268fdadd6aed9b925ff9f11/config/default.yml#L66

But your configuration is overwriting it. To avoid that, you can specify that your configuration should inherit from the default, and be merged with your additions:

https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/configuration.html#merging-arrays-using-inherit_mode

Comment: Thanks Andy, unfortunately, the documentation is not clear on how to inherit from the default.yml, I did read this section put the following into my code and it solved my problem, but I find this solution (and documentation) lacks clarity, I'm wondering if it should be updated.

inherit_mode:
  merge:
    - Exclude